# Тестирование rest-контроллера: не удаётся найти бин / spring "проскакивает" мимо mock

Tags: java, spring

Не понимаю в чем проблема. Рассматриваю 2 варианта написания теста для контроллера. В каждом свой косяк.

Структура проекта проста. Есть репозиторий (autowired datasource), есть сервис (autowired репозиторий), есть контроллер (autowired сервис). В каждом классе 1 метод. Контроллер дергает сервис, сервис дергает репозиторий, а репозиторий вызывает хранимку в БД.
Всё работает как надо, проверено и юнит тестами, и ручками через request.http. Использовались реальные данные и реальный коннект к БД. Проблема в тестах.

1 вариант). Ошибка: Parameter 0 of constructor in ru.some.controller.Controller required a bean of type 'ru.some.service.Service' that could not be found.

```java
@WebMvcTest(Controller.class)
public class IntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    private Repository repo = mock(RepositoryImpl.class)

    @Test
    void testOne() {
    doReturn(Arrays.asList("Success", "Success")).when(repo).updateMethod(Dto);

    MvcResult mvcResult = mvc.perform(post("/api/employee")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(Dto)))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andReturn();

    assertEquals("Success", mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString());
```

2 вариант). Меняю аннотации над IntegrationTest. Здесь я уверен, что spring игнорирует/незамечает замоканный репозиторий. Предыдущий тест testOne проходит! (но это потому что присоединная БД по умолчанию возвращает такие данные, что контроллер возвращает статус ОК), а вот приведённый ниже тест testTwo падает, т.к. я мокаю репозиторий на возврат "плохих" данных, но ПО РЕЗУЛЬТАТАМ ТЕСТА всё равно приходит всё тот же статус ОК.

```java
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class IntegrationTest {

    @Test
    void testTwo() {
        doReturn(Arrays.asList(errorMessage, errorMessage)).when(repo).updateMethod(Dto);

        mvc.perform(post("/api/v1/curator")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(hrAdminDto)))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
    }
}
```

В чём же может быть проблема? На что обратить внимание?

```
@Repository
public class DAOImpl implements DAO {

    @Autowired
    private final DataSource dataSource;

    private final StoredProcedure storedProcedure;

    @Autowired
    public DAOImpl(DataSource dataSource) {
        Assert.notNull(dataSource, "DataSource must be NOT NULL");

        this.dataSource = dataSource;

        StoredProcedure procedure = new GenericStoredProcedure();
        procedure.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
        procedure.setSql(StringConstant.DATABASE_STORED_PROCEDURE_NAME);
        procedure.setFunction(true);

        procedure.declareParameter(new SqlParameter(StringConstant.IN_DATE_FROM, Types.DATE));
        procedure.declareParameter(new SqlParameter(StringConstant.IN_DATE_TO, Types.DATE));
        procedure.declareParameter(new SqlParameter(StringConstant.IN_EMPLOYEE_ID, Types.VARCHAR));
        procedure.declareParameter(new SqlParameter(StringConstant.IN_DTO_ID, Types.VARCHAR));
        procedure.declareParameter(new SqlParameter(StringConstant.IN_SECOND_EMPLOYEE_ID, Types.VARCHAR));
        procedure.declareParameter(new SqlParameter(StringConstant.IN_TYPE, Types.VARCHAR));
        procedure.declareParameter(new SqlParameter(StringConstant.IN_OPERATION_TYPE, Types.VARCHAR));
        procedure.declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter(StringConstant.OUT_RESULT, Types.VARCHAR));

        procedure.compile();

        this.storedProcedure = procedure;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> updateMethod(Dto dto) {
        Map<String, Object> result = storedProcedure.execute(
                null,
                null,
                dto.getEmployeeId(),
                dto.getDtoId(),
                dto.getSecondEmployeeId(),
                StringConstant.TYPE_FIXED,
                StringConstant.OPERATION_UPDATE
        );

        return Arrays.asList((String) result.get(StringConstant.OUT_RESULT), (String) result.get(StringConstant.OUT_RESULT));
    }
}
```

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Service
@Slf4j
public class ServiceImpl implements Service {

    private final DAO DAO;

    @Autowired
    public ServiceImpl(DAO DAO) {
        Assert.notNull(DAO, "DAO must be NOT NULL");

        this.DAO = DAO;
    }

    @Override
    public String updateMethod(Dto dto) throws StoredProcedureException {
        List<String> result = DAO.updateMethod(dto);
        for (String message : result) {
            if (!message.toUpperCase().equals(StringConstant.OK)) {
                log.error(message);
                throw new StoredProcedureException(message);
            }
        }
        log.debug("update good");
        return StringConstant.OK;
    }

}
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class Controller {

    private final Service service;

    @Autowired
    public Controller(Service service) {
        Assert.notNull(service, "Service must be NOT NULL");

        this.service = service;
    }

    @PostMapping("/dto")
    public ResponseEntity<String> updateMethod(Dto dto) throws StoredProcedureException {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(service.updateMethod(dto), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>xx.xxxxxx.xxxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxxxxxxxxxxx</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>xxxxxxxxxxxx</name>
    <description>xxxxxxxxxxx</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class IntegrationTest {

    private static String dtoId = "123";
    private static String employeeId = "076587d";
    private static String secondEmployeeId = "076578";
    private static Dto dto = new Dto(
            dtoId,
            employeeId,
            secondEmployeeId
    );
    private static String errorMessage = "Something wrong!";

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Mock
    private DAO DAO;

    @Spy
    private Service service;

    @InjectMocks
    private Controller controller;

    @Test
    void updateMethodReturnOkWhenServiceReturnOk() throws StoredProcedureException, Exception {
        doReturn(Arrays.asList(StringConstant.OK, StringConstant.OK)).when(DAO).updateMethod(dto);

        MvcResult mvcResult = mvc.perform(post("/api/v1/dto")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(dto)))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andReturn();

        assertEquals(StringConstant.OK, mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString());
    }

    @Test
    void updateMethodThrowExceptionWhenServiceReturnError() throws StoredProcedureException, Exception {
        doReturn(Arrays.asList(errorMessage, errorMessage)).when(DAO).updateMethod(dto);

        mvc.perform(post("/api/v1/dto")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(dto)))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ваш `mock` уходит вникуда, ибо вы забыли указать куда его инжектить. Вам нужно сделать как-то так:

```
@InjectMocks
private YourController yourController;

@Mock
private YourRepository yourRepository;
```

Comment: Дописал, предложенный вами вариант - поймал ошибку  

org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InjectMocksException: 
Cannot instantiate @InjectMocks field named 'controller' of type 'class ru.some.controller.Controller'.
You haven't provided the instance at field declaration so I tried to construct the instance.
However the constructor or the initialization block threw an exception : Service must be NOT NULL  


Внутри контроллера есть конструктор с ассертом, который проверяет, чтобы связывание происходило без null

Comment: @echoes Мокито не может создать инстанс вашего контроллера. Аннотация тестового класса @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) должна помочь

Comment: К сожалению, всё та же ошибка

Comment: Пробовал инжектить в сервис, но тогда вываливается ошибка, что не может подтянуть DataSource для репозитория

Comment: А, кстати, я недостаточно вчитался в ошибку, у вас просит сервис инжектнуть в контейнер. Нужно добавить private YourService yourService; и аннотировать это поле @Spy(это значит, что вы инжектите не замоканый сервис в контроллер, а полноценный)

Comment: В свой 2ой вариант, я дописал: @ Mock private Repository repo; @ Spy private Service service; @ InjectMocks private Controller controller; Результат - тот же. Спринг не замечает замоканного репозитория

Comment: Не замечает в каком смысле? Он выводит ошибку какую-то?

Comment: Нет ошибки нет. Есть 2 теста, показанные в шапке. И эти тесты ведут себя так, как будто нет никакого mock на уровне репозитория. Т.е. в БД захардкожено - выдавать ОК, который пробрасывается наверх до контроллера. Я же в testTwo пытаюсь замокать репозиторий, чтобы он выдал ответ, который сервисом будет обработан как НЕ_ОК, что повлечет за собой статус код 400

Comment: А можете добавить в вопрос полный код вашего тестового класса, а также контроллер-сервис-репу + pom.xml?

Comment: Выложил. Озвучу свою конечную цель: протестировать совместно контроллер-сервис-репозиторий, причём репозиторий хочу замокать, дабы он не лез в реальную БД. Какие есть варианты, используя те инструменты, что прописаны в pom-файле?

Answer (score 0):

@ComponentScan - нужно навесить на основной класс, должно помочь;

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/768575)